# I have two before_validation callbacks. Which one gets executed first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Here is my company model which has geocoding. Basically, I want to make sure that the add_full_address method is called before the geocoding method because the geocoding method depends on the full_address. How do I get this to work? Are the validations run in order that they are written? I need them both to happen before validations are run because I want to verify that the latitude and longitude columns are populated because otherwise... I want the save to fail.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  validates :name, :organization, :title, :state, :city, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i, }

  validates :latitude , numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to:  -90, less_than_or_equal_to:  90 }
  validates :longitude, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: -180, less_than_or_equal_to: 180 }

  before_validation :add_full_address
  before_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){(obj.city_changed? || obj.state_changed?)}

  geocoded_by :full_address do |obj, results|
    if geo = results.first
      obj.latitude = geo.latitude
      obj.longitude = geo.longitude
    end
  end

  def add_full_address
    self.full_address = "#{city}, #{state}"
  end

  def d3_coordinates
    slice(:longitude, :latitude)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: [ActiveRecord::CallBacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) This will give you all the callbacks you can use. Also ruby being a synchronous language, it will run from top to bottom, but of course the callbacks are run before the validations in this case.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, validators get executed in the order that they are defined.

All before_validation callbacks will be called prior to ANY validators